# FFMPEG linking with VPX library

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, g++

I want to compile a code I am writing to work with ffmpeg but I can not link this code. I added all the required libraries but still do not work

`g++ -L/home/user/ffmpeg_build/lib -o "vpx"  ./src/vpx.o   -lpthread -lavcodec -lavutil -lvpx
/home/user/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(frame_thread_encoder.o): In function`ff_frame_thread_encoder_init':
/home/user/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.1.2/libavcodec/frame_thread_encoder.c:213: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/home/user/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(frame_thread_encoder.o): In function`ff_frame_thread_encoder_free':
makefile:45: recipe for target 'vpx' failed
/home/user/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.1.2/libavcodec/frame_thread_encoder.c:238: undefined reference to `pthread_join'
/home/user/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.1.2/libavcodec/frame_thread_encoder.c:238: undefined reference to`pthread_join'
/home/user/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(pthread_frame.o): In function `ff_frame_thread_free':
/home/user/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.1.2/libavcodec/pthread_frame.c:564: undefined reference to`pthread_join'
/home/user/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(pthread_frame.o): In function `ff_frame_thread_init':
/home/user/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.1.2/libavcodec/pthread_frame.c:704: undefined reference to`pthread_create'
/home/user/ffmpeg_build/lib/libavcodec.a(pthread_slice.o): In function `ff_slice_thread_free':
/home/user/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg-3.1.2/libavcodec/pthread_slice.c:116: undefined reference to`pthread_join'`

Answer (score 0):

`pthread` must be the last library to be linked